# param is missing or the value is empty for: quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, post, parameters

I have a POST request from a javascript file below:

```
    this.submitQuoteButton = $("<button />")
        .text("Download PDF")
        .addClass("submitQuoteButton button-success pure-button")   
        .click(function() {

            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "../quotes/create",
                data: {
                    name : "John ",
                    email: "john@john.com",
                    json: "data",
                    uid: "uid",
                 },
                 dataType:'text',
                 success: function(data,status,xhr){
                    console.log(status);
                   alert("SUCCESS!");
                 },
                 error: function(xhr,status,error){
                   console.log(status,error);
                   alert("ERROR!");
                 }

            });

        })
```

This POST calls to my quotes_controller create method where I have this

```
  def create
    @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)

    if @quote.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      redirect_to blog_path
    end
  end

  private

  def quote_params
    params.require(:quotes).permit(:uid, :name, :email, :json)
  end
```

The aim is to get the data passed in the POST request and save it to my database with the create method. Am I doing this right? I am getting a:

```
param is missing or the value is empty for: quotes
```

Does this mean there is a problem with my database set up or the create method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`quote_params` require the `quotes` key in your params. So your ajax call data should look like this:

```
data: {
  quotes: {
    name : "John ",
    email: "john@john.com",
    json: "data",
    uid: "uid",
  }
}
```

Comment: You're explaining it a little bit, so I'll remove mine answer. :)

Comment: Thanks that seemed to fix that but im now getting the error on `unknown attribute: uid` would this be a database issue?

Comment: @MikeHolford yes, it seems to be. Make sure you have `uid` column in  your `quotes` table.

Comment: @MarekLipka we have lift off! For some reason the last migration did not work. I get a SUCCESS message now :). Thank you. One last question.. Even though quote.save worked I was not redirected to root_url. I am guessing this is because it is an AJAX call. What can I do to allow me to redirect to a new page once complete?

Comment: @MikeHolford you can set `window.location` in `success` or `error` callback to redirect using javascript.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, but I've already included the `comment` key in my data object - any idea why mine still isn't working?